# Python __new__ - how can cls be different than class that __new__ is in

Tags: python

[Documentation for `object.__new__(cls[, ...])` says:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> Called to create a new instance of class `cls`. __ `new` __ is a static
>   method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes
>   the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument.

So if you have `var = MyClass()` and

```
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls):
        ...
```

Won't `cls` ALWAYS be equal to `MyClass` ?

Comment: Hint: What will happen when you create a subclass that inherits `MyClass`?

Comment: What if `__new__` was inherited by a derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls):
        print(cls)

class Yac(MyClass):
    pass

x = Yac()
print(x)
```

We get:

```
<class '__main__.Yac'>
None
```

By the way, this is fine in Python 3, but will not work in Python 2.  In Python 2 `__new__` is only supported in "new-style" classes:

```
class MyClass(object):
```

In Python 3 all classes are "new-style".